# no overload for method sendkeys takes 1 argument

Tags: c#

Por quê estou recebendo...

> no overload for method sendkeys takes 1 argument

```
using System;
using test2.Selenium;
using System.Collections.Generic;


namespace test2.ExtensionMethods

{
    public static class WebDriverExtension
    {

        public static void teste( this IWebDriver driver, string keys, string splChar)
        //this significa eu webdriver me chamo driver...estou fazendo uma extensão do metodo
        //escrevemos um novo metodo sem recomplicar o projeto...estamos adicionando um novo metodo
        //ele usou metodos ja existentes pra criar esse metodo novo...no caso adicionou mais metodos.
        {

            driver.SendKeys(keys);
            driver.SendKeys(splChar);

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: porque não tem nenhuma assinatura (sobrecarga) do método `sendkeys` com um argumento

Comment: é impossível afirmar sem ver a assinatura do método mas até faria sentido... `driver.SendKeys(keys,splChar);`